# Creating a hash in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

In my Rails app, I'm trying to use Chart.js to create a line graph with the datasets based on the data being passed from a controller (with the help of the gon gem).  Specifically, I want each dataset to be based on an account_id.

Currently, the controller contains this code where gon.balances is an array of Objects with the following fields - `account_id, balance, date`...:

balances_controller.rb:

```
....
def index
  @balances = Balance.all.order(date: :desc)

  gon.balances = @balances
end
....
```

I was wondering if it's possible to create variables dynamically in the controller like the following pseudocode, and if so, how?

- read all unique Balance.account_id
- for each Balance.account_id

  - return the account name (Account.name)
  - all the Balance.date and Balance.balance that correspond to that Balance.account_id

So in affect, I want to be able to return an array of Objects like such:

```
{:balance1.account.name => [[balance1.date, balance1.balance],
                           [balance2.date, balance2.balance]],
:balance3.account.name  => [[balance3.date, balance3.balance]] }
```

**Update:**

With Dileep Nandanam's help below, I've managed to return all the balances sorted by account_id.

balances_controller.rb:

```
  def index
    @balances = Balance.all.order(date: :desc)

    @balancesSortedByAccountId = Hash[
      Balance.all.order(date: :desc).group_by(&:account_id).map{|acc_id, acc_details|
        ["acc_#{acc_id}".to_sym, acc_details.map(&:balance)]
      }
    ]

    gon.balances = @balances
    gon.balancesSortByAccId = @balancesSortedByAccountId
  end
```

That provides a hash like this:

```
{:acc_id1 => [balance1, balance2], :acc_id2 => [balance_3] }
```

How can I modify this to provide a hash like the following:

```
{:balance1.account.name => [[balance1.date, balance1.balance],
                           [balance2.date, balance2.balance]],
:balance3.account.name  => [[balance3.date, balance3.balance]] }
```

I'm not sure how to return the name and I've tried the following to try to create the array for the date and balance but this results in two separate arrays:

```
    @balancesSortedByAccountId = Hash[
      Balance.all.order(date: :desc).group_by(&:account_id).map{|acc_id, acc_details|
        ["acc_#{acc_id}".to_sym, [acc_details.map(&:date), acc_details.map(&:balance)]]
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the objects with account_id to make a hash with acc_ids as keys and array of balances as values.

```
@balances = Hash[
  Balance.all.order(date: :desc).group_by(&:account_id).map{|acc_id, acc_details|
    ["acc_#{acc_id}".to_sym, acc_details.map(&:balance)]
  }
]
```

will give you a hash like

```
{:acc_id1 => [balance1, balance2], :acc_id2 => [balance_3] }
```

which you can turn into go variables by

```
gone.push(@balances)
```

Comment: I receive a no method error in my controller. ... 'undefined method `to_sym' for 1:Fixnum'

Comment: see the edit. "acc_#{acc_id}" will help you making a gone variable accessible as gone.acc_123

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I've updated the OP as I'd like to modify the hash to return additional information such as the date for each balance and the account name instead of id.

Comment: you can simply use [acc_details.account.name , acc_details.map(&:attributes)] as ordered pairs for hash, so that the key will be a string containing account name and value as an array of hash containing account details.

Comment: Ah, okay the value makes sense. That returns all the attributes. The key returns an error. ... undefined method `account' for #<Array:0x007f9c01aa9138>

Comment: try acc_details.first.account.name , since acc_details is an array of active record objects with same name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the data from rails into your javascript somewhere. In your example your index.html.erb could be modified to work by adding something similar to the following line right after you open your `<script>`.

```
var gon = gon || {}; gon.balances = <%= @balances.to_json %>
```

You can customize the structure of the balances collection by implementing `as_json` methods in your models which return a hash with the values you need.

Comment: In my javascript example, the data is available in gon.balances, however, in my example, gon.balances is an array of 9 Objects with some Objects having the same account_id. My issue is trying to group them so there is one Object for each account_id.

Comment: @Bhav that is unrelated to the question you asked, but look at `group_by` in the rails docs